# Add item to list inside component by outside function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How is possible update a hooked list inside a component using an external function? to be clear, suppose the pseudo-code:

list.tsx

```
const lists = () => {

const [list, setlist] = useState([]);

return <>
          The fruits are:
          { list.map( x => <>x.name<br /></> ) }
       </>

}

export { lists }
```

index.tsx

```
import { lists } from './list'
...
<Lists /> 
<button onClick={ () => lists.setlist.push({name: 'banana'}) }>Add Banana</button>
```

Any research tips are welcome.

I tried some solutions like using "static" and export a function inside a class but no sucess.

Comment: You're trying to update a child's state from the parent. Please [see this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from react docs.

Comment: thx  jsN00b, i am trying to undestand the procedure. Seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: If this is the only way that one necessarily needs to follow, then here's something I would attempt: 1. set-up a state variable in index (ie, parent) say `addToList`. 2. Pass this as a prop to the child. 3. Have the button's onClick update this variable. 4. Have `useEffect` in list.tsx (ie, child) with dependency on the prop. 5. Invoke the `setList` method within this `useEffect`. Thus, effectively the button-click will trigger the `setList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.tsx

```js
const lists = ({ list }) => {

return <>
          The fruits are:
          { list.map( x => <>x.name<br /></> ) }
       </>

}
```

index.tsx

```js
const [list, setlist] = useState([]);

...
<Lists list={list} /> 
<button onClick={ () => setlist(prev => [..prev, {name: 'banana'}]) }>Add Banana</button>
```

### State in child

list.tsx

```js
const lists = ({listsRef}) => {

const [list, setlist] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  listsRef.current = (callback) => setlist(prev => callback(prev))
}, [])

return <>
          The fruits are:
          { list.map( x => <>x.name<br /></> ) }
       </>

}
```

index.tsx

```js
const listsRef = useRef(null)

...
<Lists listsRef={listsRef} /> 
<button onClick={ () => listsRef.current(prev => [..prev, {name: 'banana'}]) }>Add Banana</button>
```

Comment: There is no way to children component hold their list?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to use the useContext hook, then all the child elements of the <context.Provider></context.Provider> tags will have access to the top level state

Comment: Except, in the example given `index.tsx` is the parent and it has no state. The state exists in the child `list.tsx`, per my understanding.

Comment: Ah, you're right haha I see it now.